# nginx sub domain proxy pass don't work

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have nginx configuration like this

**example.com configuration**

```
location /sample.php {
    #return 505; 
    proxy_pass http://sub1.example.com
}
location / {
    return 404;
}
```

**sub1.example.com configuration**

```
location / {
    try_uri $uri @missing
}
location ~ \.php {
    ...
}

location @missing {
    rewrite ^ http://sub1.example.com/index.php
}
```

when I request `sample.php` redirect in `example.com/index.php` and return 404 while I predict that must return `sub1.example.com/index.php` that is a valid URL

what is my mistake?
note: when I uncomment `return 505` that's work and return 505 in browser

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration for `sub1` is performing a redirect as you have specified a full URL on the `rewrite` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Use an internal rewrite, for example:

```
rewrite ^ /index.php last;
```

Or more simply, with:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.